# search multiple strings with square braces in gvim

Tags: regex, search, vim

gvim has a option to search multiple characters with help of [ ] like
`/delta_[123]_` can be used to search

`delta_1_`

`delta_2_`

`delta_3_`

But the same doesn't work for words like delta_one_,delta_two_,delta_three_

I tried

`/delta_[onetwothree]_`

`/delta_[one|two|three]_`

`/delta_{one|two|three}_`

Comment: `/\vdelta_(one|two|three)_`

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html